# Java Connecting to azure event hub: SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm not very used to java world, so I'm not sure if my problem is on my Azure set up, or java set up. I am getting the following exception after attempting the tutorial below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph

```
Failure while registering:     
com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.EPHConfigurationException:   
Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
```

The exception occurs during this line from the sample:

```
 host.registerEventProcessor(EventProcessor.class, options).get();
```

I did the .NET version of the tutorial with little problem. Sending and receiving works in that case. Any insights? I've been fumbling around with no luck the last few days.

Comment: Can you share the format of conectionString being used? Also make sure you are on the latest versions.

Comment: @Sreeram Im using the key as provided in the AZURE UI - long alphanumeric followed by an '='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a stupid network problem. The amqp port is whitelist only.

Answer (score 3):

I searched for your issue and find some helpful blogs which can help solving the issue, please refer to the blogs below.

1. https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/
2. http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target

The above blogs all used the tool [`InstallCert`](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) to server certificate that can be added to local keystore. Please follow the README of the GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks, looking into this. Too much multitasking.

Comment: I followed this, and it doesn't seem to have solved it. I actually do agree that this is an issue with cacerts, but going through both blogs didnt unjam my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Download the certificate with your browser and add it to your Java keystore like this:

```
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security>C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\keytool.exe -import -alias alias -file C:\path\to\file.crt -keystore C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security>cacerts -storepass changeit
```

You need to make sure to add the cert to the correct Java installation or just add to all installations, given you got more than one.

Comment: Unfortunately, i figured it out this morning. It was a closed port on my network. I did try this function and is helpful. Thanks a lot for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding certificate:

```
keytool -keystore C:\Program" "Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\security\cacerts -import -alias aliasName
-file C:\Users\cg\Downloads\springio.cer  -storepass changeit
```

To check installed certificates:

```
keytool -keystore C:\Program" "Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -list
```